# Updating a Jail-Broken iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios

I've jail-broken my iPhone 4 (iOS 4.3.3). I cannot restore it cause I don't have access to the computer that I used for jail-breaking my iPhone. Now I want to update my iPhone to iOS 5. Does it break the iPhone? or It'll work fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may run into some problems if you restore your iPhone from a backup, after upgrading. If you do a fresh install of iOS 5, you should not run into any problems.